# Гиперрссылка на текст в сообщении бота

Tags: telebot, бот, текст, гиперссылка

Подскажите, возможно ли в тексте сообщения от бота, сделать список, который при нажатии на его элемент, значение появлялось в этом же сообщении под словом.
То есть в сообщении есть список слов, а при нажатии на слово, выпадает текст, про повторном нажатии прячется. При нажатии на другое слово, открывается еще текст, сразу под этим словом. И так далее. Как в HTML на сайтах делаются списки, которые раскрываются.

Еcли есть такая возможность, подскажите как. Бот пишу на Python библиотека telebot. Большое спасибо.

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, то, кажется, такой возможности нет. Хотя я уже где-то пол года не писал ботов, поэтому точно ответить не могу. Но в качестве альтернативы можно воспользоваться inline-кнопками и  редактированием сообщения - должно получится что-то похожее на выпадающий список

Comment: Спасибо, инлайн-кнопки - очень громоздко получается. И после нажатия, нужно опять эти кнопки вешать к сообщению, чтобы вверх каждый раз не подниматься. И это так неудобно и некрасиво. 
А, что вы имеете ввиду с редактированием сообщения?

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что если ваш список состоит из нескольких слов, скажем из 3-5, чтобы лучше всего смотрелось на тлф у юзера, то в каждой инлайн-кнопке разместить слова типа "открыть/свернуть". Если юзер нажал на какую-то из кнопок, то сообщение в клавиатуре поменялось бы на "свернуть", а сообщение, за которым закреплена эта клавиатура вывела ваш текст, который вы хотели бы поместить в выпадающий список. Каждое нажатие редактирует сообщение, за которым привязана клавиатура. Мы же не можем отправить просто клавиатуру без текста. Это просто как идея, её можно улучшить. Поняли, что я имею ввиду?)

Comment: Да, идея хорошая. У меня таких слов 16 (( в два ряда. А можно просто удалять клавиатуру, выводить сообщение с информацией и к нему клавиатуру прикручивать. Так вся информация останется выше, а клавиатура будет одна, вроде не очень громоздко будет. 
Если просто сообщение менять, то человек не сможет вернуться и глянуть. В общем спасибо за идею ) сейчас буду разбираться как это сделать. Спасибо.

Comment: Я просто не знаю, как выглядит ваша архитектура проекта. Согласен, 16 будет многовато. Основная идея была в том, чтобы делать все в 1 сообщении. То есть вы можете не удаляя клавиатуру её редактировать. Точно также вы можете и отредактировать текст в этом сообщении. Таким образом текст и клавиатура всегда одна, чат у юзера не засорен, а логика работы происходит в одном сообщении, что должно быть удобно. Только вот с 16 значениями... тут уже надо вам подумать, как сделать лучше

Comment: Cпасибо большое!

Comment: @DeNRuDi, Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы после нажатие на кнопку сообщение новое заменяло старое.  весь текст сменял старый каждый раз. При любом нажатии. 

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
 def callback(call):
  if call.message:
   if call.data == 'one':
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text= 'text1.')
    
                         elif call.data == 'two':
    bot.edit_message(chat_id = message.chat.id, message_id = msg.message_id, text= 'Другой текст')

Comment: Немного трудно понять, какой код вы здесь прикрепили. Но разве `edit_message` не изменяет у вас текст? Или вы получаете какую-то ошибку? Если я правильно понял ваш код, то при нажатии на кнопку пропадет клавиатура и изменится текст

Comment: Да, не меняет. выдает ошибку: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'edit_message'. Did you mean: 'copy_message'?

Comment: Ааа, так и не существует такого метода `edit_message`:) Может в старых версиях `TeleBot` был такой метод. Есть `edit_message_text`, а еще вам может понадобится `edit_message_reply_markup` чтобы просто редактировать клавиатуру без текста

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.